# Nimrook learning Anti-Venom 2 or Drain?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I am playing BlitzBall quite a bit, and I cannot seem to learn Venom Tackle 2 or Drain with Nimrook. They are both grayed out. He is not full, and has already learned Anti-Venom.

Does anyone know what is going on with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the guide I have here, Nimrook's key techniques are Venom Tackle, Venom Tackle 2, and Anti-Drain.  In order to open up more techniques for him to learn, he first has to learn his key techniques.  If he can't learn Venom Tackle 2, then I bet he doesn't have the first one.  Correspondingly, Anti-Drain won't become available until he learns Venom Tackle 2.